# Packer - Windows Server 2012R2 - Install PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, vagrant, windows-server-2012-r2, amazon-ami, packer

I'm having trouble with installing PowerShell 5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 using Packer.

To install PowerShell 5.1, I'm using chocolatey

`powershell
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
choco install PowerShell -y`

I need to to do this for two packer builder:

- Amazon Web Services EC2 AMI.
- Hyper-V Vagrant.

With the **Amazon Web Services EC2 AMI** I've tried executing the above from the following locations

- As part of the `user_data_file` script.
- As an inline provision script.

I've added the `windows-restart` provision in the flow after the execution of the fragment.

Similarly I've tried the same with the **Hyper-V Vagrant** both as part of the *Autounattend* flow and as an inline provision.

In both cases the installation fails because the user profile is not created. At least I think that is the problem. As a reference, I've faced the exact same problem when installing sql server express.

Has anyone managed to accomplish this flow and what is your recommendation?

Comment: Have you tried looking at either of these two sites? https://chocolatey.org/packages/PowerShell or http://lifeofageekadmin.com/installing-powershell-5-windows-2012-r2/

Comment: Yes I've tried all such things. The answer below by @ferventcoder makes the most sense from what I've experienced. It explains the best what I've experienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell package uses MSU (Windows Update file). There are a couple of considerations here:

- Ensure Windows Updates Service is turned on. Chocolatey doesn't do that yet, although there is [an issue filed](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1073).
- MSUs must be run locally from the machine. So if you are running over WinRM, you instead need to have it set up a scheduled task to call `choco install` and then run it that way.

Yes, that second point is accurate. No, it is not Chocolatey's fault. That's a Microsoft design decision with MSU files. It's a real PITA.

FYI - [BoxStarter](http://boxstarter.org) handles it appropriately, and it can be used with Packer. You will find less pain if you look there.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's the best explanation about this problem I've read. Do you know if this the same reason for mssql installation failures?

Comment: Another thing to ensure is that the package works - the community package repository has no guarantee of that from day to day due to distribution rights keeping binaries out of packages (and downloading at runtime) - that failure point is not something you get when you have your own internal packages.

Comment: Where would you execute the boxstarter scripts in a packet? During the aunutended sequence or during the providing? First executed locally and second executed with winrm

Comment: TBH I know folks have done it, but I haven't dug in too far. You might look around at some of the packer templates.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try a couple of things and provide an answer here and probably a blog post. It's surprising how little information there is about this problem.

Comment: you might find interesting to know that I tried installing the `powershell` choco package with **BoxStartert** as part of packer provisioning for AWS EC2 AMI and it didn't work.

Comment: From what I read box starter is supposed to guarantee this. While using boxstarter to execute `cinst powershell` I've noticed log entries regarding Windows update service. Am I wrong to depend on boxstarter to do what is necessary when executing cinst?

Comment: I don't think so, just wanted to be sure it was turning on Windows Update service is all.